# how to set syntax=cpp for *.h files in vim

Tags: linux, vim

How do I make vim use `syntax=cpp` for *.h *.H *.C files? What line(s) should I add to vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if has("autocmd")
    " Enable file type detection
    filetype on
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.h,*.c setfiletype cpp
endif
```

I am not sure if file extension is case sensitive (I am using Windows).

Comment: The `:setf` is useless as it is already done by vim. The `:filetype on` is required though.